# Check if vector of values exists in R column then return a single True value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

if I have this dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(code = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))
```

and I have the following values:

```
my_values <- c("ABC","GHI")
```

How can i check that my object my_values is found inside the dataframe df and return a single TRUE boolean value?

I do not care for how many times the values appear I just want to return a singular TRUE boolean if any or all of the values from my_values appears in the dataframe column called code?

```
My desired result is the single boolean TRUE - i'm stuck on this and have been using the %in% operator but to no avail.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> stringr::str_detect(df, paste(my_values, collapse="|"))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
any(df$code %in% my_values)
```

Or perhaps

```
any(my_values  %in% df$code)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> TRUE %in% (my_values %in% df$code)
[1] TRUE
```

Basic R, no lib required

Answer (score 1):

If you want at least 1 of my_values in df$code to satisfy the test then:

```
result <- any(intersect(my_values, df$code))
```

Example:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 2:4
z <- 5:7
any(intersect(x, y))
[1] TRUE
any(intersect(z, y))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: There's a close parenthesis missing. And this doesn't answer the question, `any` is for logical values only.